# when React uses Canvas - drawing

Tags: reactjs, canvas

I try to draw with React. Simple onMouseMove event doesnt work. I dont know what I am doing wrong, but it display only first position of state, so rectangle with coordinates 0, 0. Maybe it is concerned with livecycle? Unfortunately There is a lot of stuff about canvas but not with React.

```
class App extends Component {

 state = { x: 0,
           y: 0
         }

 handleMouseMove(event) {
     this.setState({
       x: event.clientX,
       y: event.clientY
     });
  }


 componentDidMount() {
  const canvas = this.refs.canvas;
  canvas.width = 1000;
  canvas.height = 600;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillRect(this.state.x, this.state.y, 15,15)
 }
 render() {

   return (
     <div>

      <canvas ref="canvas"
        onMouseMove={e=>this.handleMouseMove(e)}>
      and now what!
      </canvas>
     </div>

   );
 };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ll answer this question in parts.

> Whats wrong with your implementation?

You are trying to glue state with canvas which is fine. But where are you doing it?

Inside: **componentDidMount** , From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)  this gets called only once hence you see the initial 0,0 position.

But wait!!! I am updating state and it should update every other thing right?

No! Why?

```
ctx.fillRect(this.state.x, this.state.y, 15,15) // this place updates the canvas properties
```

if you observe ctx is actually a plain js reference to the canvas dom element. **It is not a react component!**

Explain more!

1. If you wrap canvas inside a component and pass the coordinates as props then things will go fine as react will update the child when the parent's state changes.

Something like this:

```js
const Canvas = (props) =>  <canvas ref="canvas" width={props.x} height={props.y}
        onMouseMove={e=>this.handleMouseMove(e)}>
      and now what!
  </canvas>


class App extends Component {

 state = { x: 0,
           y: 0
         }

 handleMouseMove(event) {
     this.setState({
       x: event.clientX,
       y: event.clientY
     });
  }


 componentDidMount() {
 }
 render() {

   return (
     <div>

      <Canvas x={this.state.x} y={this.state.y} />
     </div>

   );
 };
}
```

2. Or a second approach is take care of updating part yourself. i.e. hook into react's update lifecycle, whenever state update happens listen to react's callback ([componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)) and do the computations yourself.

[Working js fiddle: here](https://jsfiddle.net/rishulmatta/c5dax2tu/)